# Shared folders VMWare

Tags: vmware, shared-folders

When I go to enable shared folders I get this error

```
Unable to update run-time folder sharing status: There was an error mounting Shared Folders file system inside the guest operating system.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling vmware tools and I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you installed the `build-essential` and linux-headers packages?

Comment: yes, I have both build-essintial and linux-headers.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo vmware-config-tools.pl` to your question?

Comment: It says command not found.